# Ninja Forms Populate Select with SQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ninja-forms

Scenario:
I'm using Wordpress in combination with Ninja Forms, and I would like to populate a select list with PHP/SQL.

I have created a simple form that has a select field, that I would like to populate using PHP and SQL without jQuery if possible.

After looking through the Ninja Form API and other resources, I haven't found my answer.

Using these code snippets I can populate the textbox and textarea fields but not the select field.

If more information is needed I can post it !

[Code snippet Ninjaforms](https://gist.github.com/kjohnson/ff8ff732b42173c1f49aaa4cd62c8f80#file-ninja-forms-render-default-value-php)

[And this one that works with custom post types](https://gist.github.com/iansvo/0c120b2893e0a62416e4a97ac51e859b)

```
    // filter
    add_filter( 'ninja_forms_render_default_value', 'my_change_nf_default_value', 10, 3 );
    function my_change_nf_default_value( $default_value, $field_type, $field_settings, $default_option, $field_id ) {
      if( $fh = fopen( "/var/www/virtual/wp-content/themes/xxxx/error.log", "a+" ) ){ fwrite ( $fh,$field_type."\n"); fclose( $fh ); }
      if( 'textarea' == $field_type ){
        $default_value = 'fooBARRRRRRRRR';
        $options = 'foo';
      }
      return $default_value;
    }
    apply_filters(‘ninja_forms_render_default_value’, $default_value, $field_type,  $field_settings, $field_id, $default_option);

    //Function
    function cpt_prepopulate_forms($options, $settings) {
    global $post;
    if( $fh = fopen( "/var/www/virtual/wp-content/themes/xxxx/error.log", "a+" ) ){ fwrite ( $fh,var_export($data,true)); fclose( $fh ); }
    if( $settings['id'] == 152 ) // change to your field ID
    {  
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'cash', // Change to your Custom Post type
        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) 
        {
            $options = array();
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) 
            {
                $query->the_post();
                $options[] = array(
                    'label' =>  get_the_title(),
                    'value' =>  $post->post_name,
                    'calc'  =>  null,
                    'selected' => 0
                );
            }
        } 
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    return $options;
    $conn->close();
}
add_filter('ninja_forms_render_options','cpt_prepopulate_forms', 10, 2);
// end
```

This works but I can only populate a textarea or textfield/email but no select/dropdown. The forms get generated by Ninjaforms upon load so its not possible to put custom Php between a `<select></select>`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? 
https://etzelstorfer.com/en/create-dynamic-ninja-forms-lists-post-types/

```
/******************************************
* SHOW ALL ROOMS IN FIELD WITH KEY "ROOMS"
******************************************/
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_render_options', function($options,$settings){
   if( $settings['key'] == 'rooms' ){
       $args = array(
           'post_type' => 'room',
           'orderby' => 'menu_order',
           'order' => 'ASC',
           'posts_per_page' => 100,
           'post_status' => 'publish'
       );
       $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
       if ( $the_query->have_posts() ){
           global $post;
           while ( $the_query->have_posts() ){
               $the_query->the_post();
               $options[] = array('label' => get_the_title( ), 'value' => get_the_title( ));
           }
           wp_reset_postdata(); 
       }
   }
   return $options;
},10,2);
```

Full credit to Hannes.

Comment: My issue is that the submitted values don't exist. They're not at all in the dataset or in the submission.